# In-line substring exchange in a Python string

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a string that says `"Peter has a boat, but Steve has a car."` . I need to change that to `"Steve has a boat, but Peter has a car."`  The only way I can think of doing this is an ugly three-step `replace()` with a placeholder:

```
"Peter has a boat, but Steve has a car.".replace("Peter","placeholder").replace("Steve","Peter").replace("placeholder","Steve")
```

Is there a more concise and proper - and less awful and ugly - way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using `re`

```py
import re
string = "Peter has a boat, but Steve has a car."
re.sub(r"(Peter|Steve)", lambda match: "Peter" if match.group()=="Steve" else "Steve", string)
```

Comment: Minor tweak: Since the part being matched is the whole amount to replace, you don't want/need to capture it again in a capturing group internally. Change `r"(Peter|Steve)"` to `r"(?:Peter|Steve)"` to make it a non-capturing group which (at least in some regex engines, haven't examined Python's too closely) saves some work (and if you're doing this a lot, you may want to `re.compile` the pattern, then call `compiledpat.sub(lambda..., string)` to save cache maintenance and possible recompilation costs of the top-level module functions).